# request uri showing include path

Tags: php, include

I am trying to get the URL from a function I wrote. But because the function is included into the file, its brining back the include path and not the url. Is there a work around?

i should get /example.php but instead i get includes/url-logger.php

this is done via $_SERVER['request_uri']

cheers

Comment: Examples of the string you get and the string you expect would be tremendously helpful. ;-) Ideally along with the code that produces it.

Comment: ive tryed simplyfying it

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the special `__FILE__` inside the PHP file you want the name of. This will give you the full server path (e.g. something like `/var/www/sitename/file.php`) so to get the URL, you'll need to do something like this:

```
$path = str_replace( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', __FILE__ );
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;
```

(NB you might need an extra forward slash somewhere...)

EDIT: based on the comment on the other answer, you might just need `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean but perhaps `echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` and `echo __FILE__` will help?

Comment: I have the url; http://www.example.com/example.php i need the /example.php part but because say includes/logvisit.php is includes from the examples.php instead of getting examples.php back i get includes/logvisit.php... this is on request_uri too